# Add Feature Class from Geodatabase Dataset to MXD using ArcPy Standalone Script?

Tags: arcpy, error-000732

I am trying to add a Feature Class from a Geodatabase Dataset to an MXD and save a copy like this but I am getting following errors on each methos

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\MXDs"
MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\MXDs\map.mxd")
DF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD)[0]

lyr = arcpy.mapping.Layer("C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\GDBs\Delaware.gdb\Kent\Kent")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DF, layer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
MXD.saveACopy('newmxd.mxd')
del MXD
print(" Done")
```

[image]

and

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\MXDs"
MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\MXDs\map.mxd")
DF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD)[0]

lyr = "C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\GDBs\Delaware.gdb\Kent\Kent"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr, 'shplyr')
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DF, lyr, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
print(" Step 4")
MXD.saveACopy('newmxd.mxd')
del MXD
print(" Done")
```

[image]

Comment: Per the [documentation for arcpy.mapping.layer](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm), this line is looking for a layer instead of a feature class. You can try to create a layer (arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management) first.

Comment: What error do you receive in the second codeblock?

Comment: You left out the "raw" modifier on the `lyr` variable declaration -- the path with characters  "\a","\A", "\G", "\D" and "\K" does not exist.

Comment: Oh, good catch! I'll edit my answer to include the leading r

Comment: Thanks Vince but can you please let me know what do you mean exactly by `you left out the "raw" modifier on the lyr variable declaration -- the path with characters "\a","\A", "\G", "\D" and "\K" does not exist`

Comment: Please always provide error messages as text rather than (or in addition to) pictures.

Comment: @Mona - this article has good info on escape characters within Python: [Avoiding windows backslash problems with python's raw strings](https://blog.lerner.co.il/avoiding-windows-backslash-problems-with-pythons-raw-strings/).

Answer (score 1):

Try the following adjustment to your code. Per the documentation for arcpy.mapping.layer, this line is looking for a layer instead of a feature class. You already tried to create a layer (arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management) first, but you are referencing the feature class again instead of the layer.

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\MXDs"
MXD = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(r"C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\MXDs\map.mxd")
DF = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(MXD)[0]

lyr = r"C:\arcgis\ArcTutor\AAA\GDBs\Delaware.gdb\Kent\Kent"

arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(lyr, 'shplyr')
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(DF, 'shplyr', "AUTO_ARRANGE")
print(" Step 4")
MXD.saveACopy('newmxd.mxd')
del MXD
print(" Done")
```

Comment: Thanks smiller but I am still getting the same error

Comment: The valueerror or 000372? At what line does it fail? You can add additional print statements to see at what point the code is failing.

Comment: the 000372 error

Comment: Edited to include "r" at the beginning of lyr path. If this doesn't work Double check the paths -- e.g. Are you certain that there is a feature class named Kent, within a feature dataset named Kent, in the Delaware GDB, in that directory?  The arcpy example shows MakeFeatureLayer can be used with GDBs: `arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management("C:/data/mexico.gdb/cities","cities_lyr")`.  The docs do say that complex feature classes can't be converted in this manner - what data type is the Kent feature class?

Comment: Thanks again smiller but now I am getting erroe like `File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.6\ArcPy\arcpy\mapping.py", line 49, in AddLayer
    assert isinstance(add_layer, Layer)
AssertionError`

Comment: At what line does the assertion error occur? It sounds like this is after making the feature layer, is that correct? What is the last successful line?

Answer (score 0):

The below worked for me, in a standalone python script. The mxd.saveAsCopy seems to have issues, thus would suggest that you first copy the original mxd, rename it and then use it. To do this you can use os and shutil.

```
import arcpy, os, shutil
dest = r'C:\Users\........\Desktop'
mymxd_old = "lakes1.mxd" # This can be a parameter / input
mymxd_new = "Lakes2.mxd" # This could be parameter  / input
shutil.copy(os.path.join(dest, mymxd_old), os.path.join(dest,mymxd_new))

mymxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument( os.path.join(dest, mymxd_new))
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mymxd)[0]
fc =  r'C:\Users\......\2018.gdb\Rivers'
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "Add_Rivers")

layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("Add_Rivers")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df, layer, "AUTO_ARRANGE")
mymxd.save()

del mymxd
```